# Conan / CMake Toolchain file defaulted to

Tags: docker, cmake, conan

I have a docker container used to build a conan package which requires a CustomUtils.cmake from a another conan package. The conan genrator I use is only the `CMakeDeps` generator (no `CMakeToolchain` generator).

The build works fine on a build agent. However, when I try run the docker locally and then execute the same commands (`conan install . -pr:h hprofile -pr:b bprofile -if=build`, `conan build . -bf=build`) the build fails because CustomUtils.cmake module is not found. The cmake output of the two builds look sliglty different: is different and a . Specifically cmake defaults to the poky toolchain file

```
-- Toolchain file defaulted to '/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake'
```

Also the following cmake output is also missing locally:

```
-- Conan: Target declared 'CustomUtils::CustomUtils'
-- Conan: Including build module from '/home/agent/work/.conan/data/CustomUtils/0.1/_/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/CustomTestUtils.cmake'
```

Failing build because CustomUtils.cmake cannot be found

```
----Running------
> cd '/work/build' && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Linux" -DCONAN_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH="/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux" -DCONAN_IN_LOCAL_CACHE="OFF" -DCONAN_COMPILER="clang" -DCONAN_COMPILER_VERSION="14" -DCONAN_LIBCXX="libc++" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS="OFF" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/work/build/package" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR="lib" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR="include" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR="include" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR="share" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/work/build" -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="/work/build" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY="ON" -DCONAN_EXPORTED="1" -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE="NEVER" -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE="ON" -Wno-dev '/work'
-----------------
-- Toolchain file defaulted to '/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake'
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.3
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-clang - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Conan version 1.53.0
cmake version 3.22.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for CustomUtils.cmake

CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH].

    /work/build

  

  CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH].

  

  Env variable CustomUtils_DIR [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH env variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH env variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  Paths specified by the find_package HINTS option.

    none

  Standard system environment variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/x86_64-pokysdk-linux
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-musl
    /usr/local
    /usr
    /

  

  CMake User Package Registry [CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY].

    none

  CMake variables defined in the Platform file
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH].

    /work/build/package
    /usr/X11R6
    /usr/pkg
    /opt

  

  CMake System Package Registry
  [CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY].

    none

  Paths specified by the find_package PATHS option.

    none

  find_package considered the following locations for the Config module:

    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/CustomUtilsConfig.cmake
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/customutils-config.cmake
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/CustomUtilsConfig.cmake
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/customutils-config.cmake
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/CustomUtilsConfig.cmake
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/customutils-config.cmake
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/CustomUtilsConfig.cmake
    /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/customutils-config.cmake

  The file was not found.
```

Working build on build agent:

```
----Running------
15:10:18   > cd '/home/agent/work/build' && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Linux" -DCONAN_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH="/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux" -DCONAN_IN_LOCAL_CACHE="OFF" -DCONAN_COMPILER="clang" -DCONAN_COMPILER_VERSION="14" -DCONAN_LIBCXX="libc++" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS="OFF" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/agent/work/build/package" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR="lib" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR="include" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR="include" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR="share" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/agent/work/build" -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="/home/agent/work/build" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY="ON" -DCONAN_EXPORTED="1" -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE="NEVER" -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE="ON" -Wno-dev '/home/agent/work'
15:10:18   -----------------
15:10:18   -- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.3
15:10:18   -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.3
15:10:18   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
15:10:18   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
15:10:18   -- Check for working C compiler: /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-clang - skipped
15:10:18   -- Detecting C compile features
15:10:18   -- Detecting C compile features - done
15:10:18   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
15:10:18   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
15:10:18   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-clang++ - skipped
15:10:18   -- Detecting CXX compile features
15:10:18   -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
15:10:18   Conan version 1.53.0
15:10:18   cmake version 3.22.3
15:10:18   
15:10:18   CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
15:10:18   -- Conan: Target declared 'CustomUtils::CustomUtils'
15:10:18   -- Conan: Including build module from '/home/agent/work/.conan/data/CustomUtils/0.1/_/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/CustomTestUtils.cmake'
15:10:18   CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
15:10:18     find_package considered the following paths for CustomUtils.cmake
15:10:18   
15:10:18       /home/agent/work/build/FindCustomUtils.cmake
15:10:18       /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindCustomUtils.cmake
15:10:18   
15:10:18     The file was not found.
15:10:18   
15:10:18     <PackageName>_ROOT CMake variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       none
15:10:18   
15:10:18     CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       /home/agent/work/build
15:10:18   
15:10:18   
15:10:18   
15:10:18     CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH variables
15:10:18     [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH].
15:10:18   
15:10:18   
15:10:18   
15:10:18     Env variable CustomUtils_DIR [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       none
15:10:18   
15:10:18     CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH env variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       none
15:10:18   
15:10:18     CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH env variables
15:10:18     [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       none
15:10:18   
15:10:18     Paths specified by the find_package HINTS option.
15:10:18   
15:10:18       none
15:10:18   
15:10:18     Standard system environment variables
15:10:18     [CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr
15:10:18       /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux
15:10:18       /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/x86_64-pokysdk-linux
15:10:18       /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
15:10:18       /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-musl
15:10:18       /usr/local
15:10:18       /usr
15:10:18       /
15:10:18   
15:10:18   
15:10:18   
15:10:18     CMake User Package Registry [CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       none
15:10:18   
15:10:18     CMake variables defined in the Platform file
15:10:18     [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       /home/agent/work/build/package
15:10:18       /usr/X11R6
15:10:18       /usr/pkg
15:10:18       /opt
15:10:18   
15:10:18   
15:10:18   
15:10:18     CMake System Package Registry
15:10:18     [CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY].
15:10:18   
15:10:18       none
15:10:18   
15:10:18     Paths specified by the find_package PATHS option.
15:10:18   
15:10:18       none
15:10:18   
15:10:18     find_package considered the following locations for the Config module:
15:10:18   
15:10:18       /home/agent/work/build/CustomUtilsConfig.cmake
15:10:18   
15:10:18     The file was found at
15:10:18   
15:10:18       /home/agent/work/build/CustomUtilsConfig.cmake
```

Any idea why the build succeeds on the agent but not locally even with the same docker image is used (both freshly pulled and up to date)?

Why is CMake defaulting to a toolchain file that doesn't seem to be specified anywhere. Are there any environment variables to configure this behaviour?

Comment: Is the `conan install` call able to resolve and install `CustomUtils`? Maybe take a look at the debug output of that step.

Comment: Yes, the `conan install` step works without issues. I found that there seems to be an issue setting up the docker container on the build agent. Some of the environment variables, specifically OE_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE, is not set.